# How to implement authorization combined with a custom username validation in wcf

Tags: wcf, validation, authorization

I have a custom username/password validation in a WCF service. I followed the steps on [this site](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2010/03/22/a-simple-wcf-service-with-username-password-authentication-the-things-they-don-t-tell-you/) to create this authentication.

I want to develop some kind of authorization based on the already validated credentials but don't know where to find this kind of information. I googled a lot and found lots of ways to regulate authorization but can't find a way to base this authorization on the custom username validation.

I am new to wcf and overwhelmed by all it's different kinds of methods.
Can someone provide me with some links where i can find information about this specific subject?

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc948343.aspx) article to be a great summary of all the things WCF has to offer to support authorization. The article starts with the simplest implementation and then discusses each incremental step in complexity all the way to full blown claims based authorization.

Based on the information you provided regarding your specific situation, I would recommend that you create a custom implementation of IPrincipal, as illustrated in Figure 3 of the article I linked. I have included the code sample from the article here as well.

```
class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    IIdentity _identity;
    string[] _roles;
    Cache _cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;

    public CustomPrincipal(IIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    // helper method for easy access (without casting)
    public static CustomPrincipal Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Thread.CurrentPrincipal as CustomPrincipal;
        }
    }

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

    // return all roles (custom property)
    public string[] Roles
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureRoles();
            return _roles;
        }
    }

    // IPrincipal role check
    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        EnsureRoles();

        return _roles.Contains(role);
    }

    // cache roles for subsequent requests
    protected virtual void EnsureRoles()
    {
        // caching logic omitted – see the sample download
    }
}
```

In the custom username and password validator referenced in your original post, you would simply populate an instance of the new IPrincipal and attach it to the static value Thread.CurrentPrincipal. This will allow you to then simply decorate any methods you wish to control access to by using the PrincipalPermission attribute as illustrated below. This code sample is also Figure 1 from the article I linked.

```
class Service : IService {
  // only 'users' role member can call this method
  [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = 'users')]
  public string[] GetRoles(string username) {
    // only administrators can retrieve the role information for other users
    if (ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name != username) {
      if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole('administrators')) {
        ...
      }
      else {
        // access denied
        throw new SecurityException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```